# how can I adding quickdialog to my project?

Tags: quickdialog

http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog

**In YOUR project configuration:
in the Build Phases, Add QuickDialog (the lib, not the example app) as a Target Dependency
in the Link Binary With Libraries section, add the libQuickDialog.a library**

I don't know how to do this ……
please tell me the detail about this step.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Click your project in the project navigator (on the left hand side, at the top, with a blue icon next to it).

2) Select your app under the Targets heading.

3) Click the Build Phases tab.

4) Expand the Target Dependencies, and click the + button. Add the one called QuickDialog (not QuickDialogExample).

5) Expand Link Binary with Libraries and click the + button. Add libQuickDialog.a.